# Downgrade Android 4.2 to 4.1

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, 4.2-jelly-bean, downgrade

I have an Asus K013, an old tablet running android 4.2. As i have no use for it now, i want to downgrade it to android 4.1 as Wiimote compatibility is broken in 4.2+. However, I don't think it runs stock android (though I'm not sure) so I'm not sure how I would downgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

K013 (otherwise known as MeMO Pad 7 or ME176C) comes with Android 4.4 minimum, as shown on [PhoneArena](https://www.phonearena.com/phones/Asus-MeMO-Pad-7_id8697) and supplied by the [HelpDesk](https://www.asus.com/Tablets/ASUS_MeMO_Pad_7_ME176C/HelpDesk_Download/) of ASUS themselves. Therefore, there's no lower version of official OS you could downgrade to. Since it's an Intel-based device, you won't be able to find custom ROMs for it either. Not to mention that there are only a handful of examples where custom ROMs can have a lower Android version than the lowest provided by stock ROMs.

**TL;DR:** No you can't.